# Method to get list headers & filters via jQuery SPServices CAML GetListItems or similar?

Tags: jquery, filter, spservices, caml, viewfields

Is there a method similar to GetListItems to grab the column headers and/or filters for a list?  Or a way to use GetListItems to get that information?

Comment: You mean you want to get the fields associated with a list?

Comment: The names or references of the fields, yes.  The filters associated with each field as well, though if SharePoint generates those when it displays the list, I suppose I will have to duplicate that effort.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `GetList` [operation](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetList).

Example from the link:

```
$().SPServices({
  operation: "GetList",
  listName: "Master List",
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
    console.log(xData.responseText);
    $(xData.responseXML).find("Fields > Field").each(function() {
      var $node = $(this);
      console.log( "Type: " + $node.attr("Type") + " StaticName: " + $node.attr("StaticName") );
    });
  }
});
```